# Is Grzegorczyk's theory $TC$ interpretable in Robinson Arithmetic $Q$

Tags: logic, reference-request, foundations

The question is in the title.  It is known that $TC$ interprets Robinson Arithmetic $Q$ (Svejdar proved this), but I am interested in seeing the proof of the other direction.  My motivation for the question is to study some claims of Edward Nelson and his system of predicative arithmetic which I understand is based on $Q$.  If my question is already answered in the literature, please provide the reference.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is.  The theory is easily interpretable in IΔ<sub>0</sub>, which is interpretable in Q. For the later, see for example [Interpretability in Robinson's Q](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/1903/1903-001.ps) (Ferreira, Fernando; Ferreira, Gilda.  Bull. Symbolic Logic 19 (2013), no. 3, 289--317.)